# Is there a way to get Java's unique hashcode from objects like HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hash

I believe that if I declare a HashMap and repeatedly feed it instances of Map.Entry eventually a hashcode will collide with another hashcode even if the two keys (which happen to be Strings for my needs) are different.

At that point HashMap and other classes that use hashing will produce a different hash code which serves as the real key for internal use. (Edit: this turned out to be not true. Please see the selected answer.)

Is there a way to get that internal key?  The reason I want it is because a 32 bit key is more efficient memory and speed-wise than the real world key which would be a (possibly) longish string.

I can make a hash code registry for my Strings but why bother if Java already can do this.

Comment: Look at `System.identityHashCode(Object o)`.

Comment: *"I can make a hash code registry for my Strings but why bother if Java already can do this."*  You do realize that `String` caches its hashcode, right?  It will only compute the hash the first time it is requested.  This is possible since Strings are immutable.

Comment: @Mark Peters, AFAIK the hashcode of a String is not guaranteed to be unique unless there is a string pool manager that avoids creating duplicate strings which may or may not be the case for the JVM.

Comment: @Mark Peters, and even if there are no duplicate strings, there still is no guarantee.

Comment: @broiyan: Fair enough, I wasn't sure if this hash "registry" was meant to enable fast look-up (where mostly unique is fine, and your worry was the hash implementation itself) or to represent all strings as 32-bit integers.  I thought it was pretty obvious that you couldn't do the latter, so I assumed the former.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. You *can't* get a unique 32 bit number for every possible object in your system.

The simplest proof for this is that on a 64bit JVM with sufficient amounts of memory you can *easily* have more than 2^32 objects: thus you'd need more than 2^32 different hash values. But since you only have 32 bits to *store* those hash values, you can't get more than 2^32 different hash values. This is called the [Pidgeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Also: [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) *doesn't* produce a "unique hash code": it simply stores all elements with the same hash code in the same bucket (in a linked list) and checks every one of them using `equals()` if it has to retrieve one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory link: [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) -- only a very few cases even allow for [minimal perfect hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_perfect_hashing) and this does *not* cover a general hash table like `HashMap`. There are actually *two* factors against this which are both related to the [pigeon hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle):

1. As stated by others, there may be more objects than can be unique represented by with an `int`: the *hash value* cannot, therefor, cannot be guaranteed unique. That is, the range of the hash function is less than the domain of unique objects.
2. The number of buckets used in the hash table is [significantly] less than the domain of hash values: this results in the *inability to guarantee a unique bucket is used*: generally, `bucket_used = hash % bucket_count`. (A hash table with 2^32 buckets for 42 entries would be hardly practical; in this case the domain of the hash value, provided it is larger than the bucket count, is largely irrelevant.)

(Additionally, [a hash code has a strict relationship with object-equality](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), if each object did have a "unique system hash code" then said hash code could be used in an object-identity map *but not an object-equality map*.)

Due to these reasons, [collision resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) *is always required* in a general hash-table implementation. (The OpenJDK 7 [HashMap implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html) uses a Linked-List Chaining approach and final equality is decided by `==` and `equals()`, in that order.)

While the JDK implementation *does use an internal "hash mixer"* with the goal of creating a better-distribution of hash values, this is irrelevant to how hash tables handle collisions and, like the original hash function, is subject to the same rules discussed above.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't produce a different hash code. It will maintain several entries with the *same* hash code, and an easy way to find all entries with the same hash code. When you try to find a key with that hash code, it will check for equality with all the hash-matching keys, until it either finds an equality match or runs out. Read the code for `HashMap` to find out more details.

How would you expect `HashMap` to produce a genuinely unique `int` hash when there can be more than 2<sup>32</sup> distinct objects?